# Chromium not remembering all tabs and running slow

Tags: chromium

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit and Chromium 34.0.1847.116 Ubuntu 14.04 aura (260972).  I've noticed a few problems...

1) Despite having the setting "Continue where you left off" checked, only some of the tabs are reopened when I start up Chromium.  I typically have about 10 tabs open when I close Chromium so I can't see that being some limit - hasn't been a problem in the past.

2) If I right click a link and open in a new window, that window can take up to a minute to load the page and once loaded, runs sluggishly (scrolling is slow or if a YouTube video, runs as though I've got poor bandwidth).

I've removed Chromium (apt-get purge) and then also removed the directories ~/.cache/chromium and ~/.config/chromium and then did a reinstall of Chromium but to no avail.  Interestingly after running what should be a clean Chromium, I hit CTRL + H and all my browser history was there...

FWIW, I also tried changing video drivers - switching from Nouveau to Nvidia (all three versions which available to me) and the problem persists.

I finally decided to reinstall 14.04 and the problem returns.

I've got the pepper flash plugin installed so I don't know if that has something to do with this, although this is the first time I've (knowingly) installed this plugin.  I've never had this problem on 13.10 with Chromium and have had no problems with Firefox.  I also have the webmail ad blocker plugin installed but that's never given me trouble in the past either.

Any one else having a similar issue?  Any ideas on what to try next...?

Update: I've reported a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1310849

Thanks in advance,

Bernard.

Answer (score 0):

I started having this problem after the switch to the Aura builds and haven't found a real answer yet. As a workaround, you can downgrade to Chromium from 13.10 by installing [this package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/chromium-browser). Find the deb package to download at the bottom of the page, select the one for the architecture you're running.